# System date format

Tags: java, file, date-format

Is there anyway to force the computer to change its date format by code using java? My app stores the date in a string using a specified format and in a file on disk. The format chosen affects only the string variable but not the file as its forced to use the system regional settings. I tried to set the Locale or change the default locale in SimpleDateFormat() but it didn't go. I don't understand why the system settings force a String to follow a date pattern. Any clarification would be appreciated.

Comment: Show us your code. But before that, see [how to complete a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: This Question makes no sense. Provide much more detail, and example code. If you you are writing a date-time value as text to a file, that should be easy to demonstrate in a code snippet extracted from your app.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Question is not at all clear. No such thing as "System date format".

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

The old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java have proven to be troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, and `SimpleDateFormat`. These are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.

## ISO 8601

If you are serializing a date-time value to disk in a file as text, use the standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats. These formats are intuitive across cultures, unambiguous, and growing in popularity including in new internet and information standards.

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes use ISO 8601 formats by default when parsing/generating strings of date-time values.

Get the current moment in UTC with a resolution of up to nanoseconds using the [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now();
```

Generate a string to represent that moment as text in standard ISO 8601 format.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-12-04T06:12:13.455Z

Easy to parse back into an object again.

```
Instant instant = Instant.parse( "2016-12-04T06:12:13.455Z" );
```

Usually best to work in UTC, but you can adjust that moment into a time zone if desired.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z );
String outputZdt = zdt.toString();
```

> 2016-12-04T01:12:13.455-05:00[America/Montreal]

See [live code at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/2kIEVm).

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [*ThreeTenABP*](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts ***ThreeTen-Backport*** (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time.

Comment: Thank you very much Basil for your help. You made it clear, I need a lot more of reading and practice.I meant by System Date Format the settings in control panel -> region where the user set the date and time format for the OS. That format seems to override everything outside the JVM environment like the file I set on the system. I'm sorry I didn't reply earlier as I didn't get an email notification of your comment.